# Define Where Response.Redirect Should Go To Depending On Session For A Checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

On my asp.net webfrom process i have a 5 step process inwhich on Step02 i have a `checkboxlist`. When the user clicks the 'Next' button on this page they are taken to Step03 no matter what services they selected but if the user only selected  'Site content uploading' or 'Site content & layout checking' then from my Step03 'Next' button click they should be directed to my 'Confirmation' page other wise they should be directed to 'Step04' but i can't figure it out.

Code below is for my 'Submit' button click for Step02

```
protected void Step02SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SessionSaving();
    Response.Redirect("/Quotation/Step03.aspx");
}
```

Code below is for my the session storing of the checked checkboxes for Step02

```
private void SessionSaving()
{
    List<string> selections = new List<string>();
    foreach (ListItem listItem in Services.Items)
    {
        if (listItem.Selected)
        {
            selections.Add(listItem.Value);
        }
    }

    Session["Step02Services"] = selections;
}
```

Code below is for my HTML of my `checkboxlist` for Step02

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" id="Services" CssClass="CheckboxList">
    <asp:ListItem Text="All services" Value="All services"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Site content uploading only" Value="Site content uploading only"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Site content &amp; layout checking" Value="Site content &amp; layout checking"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Testing on various browsers" Value="Testing on various browsers"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Testing all website functionality" Value="Testing all website functionality"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Responsive design (Design/Implemtation only)" Value="Responsive design (Design/Implemtation only)"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Responsive design (Testing only)" Value="Responsive design (Testing only)"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: "Can't figure it out" is too general of a question. Did you try anything? Any errors?

Comment: @Andrei No i havn't tried anything because i dont know how to get my session values back. If each checkbox was stored individually, i would be ok

Comment: Just do `Session["Step02Services"] as List<string>`, check for null and you should have selections back

Comment: @Andrei but if the user has only selected 'Site content uploading' only or 'Site content &amp; layout checking' or 'Site content uploading & Site content &amp; layout checking' then i want them to go to a different page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your step03 Next event, you just need to read from your session, and see if they had selected one of those two checkboxes and redirect accordingly.

```
protected void Step03SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<string> selections = Session["Step02Services"] as List<string>;

  if (selections != null) {
    if (selections.Contains("Site content uploading") || selections.Contains("Site content & layout checking")) {
      Response.Redirect("/YourConfirmationPage.aspx");
    } else {
      Response.Redirect("/Step04.aspx");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please review my updated post as i completly missed valuble details out which now may invloke you anser or need an amendment as the code needs to be in my Step03.cs (the page after the checkboxlist) and not my Step02.cs (the page where the checkboxlist is)

Comment: I have updated my answer.